How Does Autoref Print Prefixes for Sublevels of Enumerate in LaTeX?
I am creating a list environment based on the enumerate environment. This environment will have up to two levels. For this, I am calling the enumitem package and calling the following initial settings.
% Package name: abnt-secoes-sumario-nbr60242012-60272012
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
% Provides the abnt-secoes-sumario package with the version date
\ProvidesPackage{abnt-secoes-sumario}[2024/05/10 Implementation of ABNT NBR 6024:2012 and NBR 6027:2012 standards version 0.1]
% ...
% Items and subitems

% The enumitem package allows you to customize lists in LaTeX, controlling the appearance and formatting: used to define items and subitems.

\RequirePackage{enumitem} 

\newlength{\lenspace} % new length to measure the length of \space
\settowidth{\lenspace}{\space} % measures the length of \space and assigns it to \lenspace

% Global settings for the enumerate environment
\setlist[enumerate,1]{% Settings for the first level (items)
    label=\alph*), % Defines the item label
    ref=\alph*,
    align=left,    % Defines that the items will be aligned to the left
    leftmargin=*,  % 
    labelindent=\parindent, %
    labelsep=\lenspace, % controls the space between the label and the start of the text.
} % 
\setlist[enumerate,2]{% Settings for the second level (subitems)
    label=--,     % Defines the item label
    ref=\arabic*,
    align=left,   % Defines that the items will be aligned to the left
    leftmargin=*, %
    labelindent=0pt, % 
    labelsep=\lenspace, % controls the space between the label and the start of the text. 
    parsep=0pt,   % controls the space after
    topsep=0pt    % controls the space before
} % 

% Creates a new list environment that behaves like the above-defined enumerate environment

% Creates a new environment called item
\newenvironment{alinea}{\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}

\RequirePackage[%
                colorlinks=true,%
                linkcolor=blue,%
                citecolor=blue,%
                ]{hyperref}%

% Creates new alias counters for each level of the list

% Redefines the name of the \autoref command for each level of the list
\newcommand{\enumiaautorefname}{
    \renewcommand{\itemautorefname}{item}
}
\newcommand{\enumiiautorefname}{
    \renewcommand{\itemautorefname}{subitem}
}

As you may have noticed, these lines are inside a package that I am creating and that will be called in my tex document which is loaded with the memoir class. A minimal code of what I am trying to do is as follows.
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
    
    % Insert the microtype package
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{helvet}  % Uses the 'tgheros' font, which is similar to Arial
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}  % Sets the default font as sans-serif
    \usepackage{abnt-secoes-sumario} % name of my package
    
    \begin{document}
    \OnehalfSpacing
    Some text that being very long should form a paragraph, since it explains something and then enumerates some options listed in the form of items and subitems below. Here presenting two ways to do this. First with the enumerate environment:
    \begin{enumerate} % calling this just for testing
        \item It is interesting to note that after line comes a subline: \label{enumi:a}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item subitem 1; \label{enumii:a:first}
            \item subitem 2;\label{enumii:a:second}
            \item subitem 3. \label{enumii:a:third}
        \end{enumerate}
        \item item 2: \label{enumi:b}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item subitem 4 \label{enumii:b:first}
            \item subitem 5 \label{enumii:b:second}
            \item subitem 6 \label{enumii:b:third}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    
    As mentioned in \autoref{enumi:a} and in \autoref{enumii:a:second}...

\begin{quote}
    As mentioned in \autoref{enumi:a} and in \autoref{enumii:a:second} ...
    
    In the \autoref{enumii:a:second}, of \autoref{enumi:a} ...
    
    In the first subalínea, of alínea c ... (expected output)
    
    Na primeira subalínea, da alínea c ... (Portuguese version)
\end{quote}
    
    And now with the new alinea environment:
    \begin{alinea}
        \item It is interesting to note that after line comes a subline. We need to understand also how this behavior will be in the alinea. \label{alinea:a}
        \begin{alinea}
            \item subalinea 1: it is not enough just to test a short word, it is necessary to see how an item behaves when the text is long. Here we had an expected behavior. \label{subalinea:a:first}
            \item subalinea 2 \label{subalinea:a:second}
            \item subalinea 3 \label{subalinea:a:third}
        \end{alinea}
        \item alinea 2 \label{alinea:b}
        \begin{alinea}
            \item subalinea 4 \label{subalinea:b:first}
            \item subalinea 5 \label{subalinea:b:second}
            \item subalinea 6 \label{subalinea:b:third}
        \end{alinea}
        \item in this item I want to understand how the distance between one item and another behaves when there is no subitem.
        \item this is important for us to understand if the items are behaving as the standard asks.
    \end{alinea}
    
    \begin{quote}
        As mentioned in \autoref{alinea:a} and in \autoref{subalinea:a:second} ...
    
        In the \autoref{subalinea:a:second}, of \autoref{alinea:a} ...
    
        In the first subalínea, of alínea c ... (expected output)
    
        Na primeira subalínea, da alínea c ... (Portuguese version)
\end{quote}
    
    Just to get an idea it is good to understand how the distance between the alinea environment and the text after the alinea environment is closed.
\end{document}

The result we expect to obtain in the PDF output is:

“In the first subalinea, of alinea c …”

However, what I get is the following output: 
Here, the counter would print first, second, third, etc. for subitem (enumii) and a, b, c, etc. for item (enumi). The point to note would be the desire for autoref to print the word subitem as a suffix and not a prefix as it normally does. An additional question then would be: is this possible?
As you can see, I am trying to reference the items in the text by calling the autoref command from the hyperref package. However, looking at the hyperref documentation, it calls the internal \itemautorefname command, based on a counter that is associated with the type of environment. As far as I can tell, autoref does not distinguish between enumi and enumii. For him, they are all of the item type and that’s why he always prints the word item as a prefix. The hyperref package suggests an alternative approach based on the aliascnt package, but this approach was used as an example for the theorem environment. See the example that the hyperref package presents:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newaliascnt{lemma}{theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[lemma]{Lemma}
\aliascntresetthe{lemma}
\providecommand*{\lemmaautorefname}{Lemma}
\begin{document}
We will use \autoref{a} to prove \autoref{b}.
\begin{lemma}\label{a}
Nobody knows.
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}\label{b}
Nobody is right.
\end{theorem}.
\end{document}

According to the hyperref document, this approach is a way to try to trick autoref:

“Hint: \autoref works via the counter name that the reference is based
on. Sometimes \autoref chooses the wrong name, if the counter is used
for different things. For example, it happens with \newtheorem if a
lemma shares a counter with theorems. Then package aliascnt provides a
method to generate a simulated second counter that allows the
differentiation between theorems and lemmas:”

Unfortunately, I am not able to implement this approach to have the effect I want. So, I would like help to make my code work.

cleveref or zref-cleveref might be useful here. The former, at least, can work with autoref provided it is loaded after hyperref. You don't really want the alias here because the counters are not the same: enumi and enumii are distinct.

You don't mention the errors this surely gives you. That it fails to produce the output you want is not even relevant while you're getting errors. You can't define an environment item without breaking LaTeX's \item, which will break all lists.

@cfr : I apologize. The code I presented is a reduced version of my code. Regrettably, I did not test the minimal code before posting it here. But now I have made the corrections and it should run normally.

No problem. Easily done. Even when I test, I sometimes mess it up.

Is alinea just enumerate or is there meant to be a difference?

The Brazilian standard, ABNT NBR 6024:2012, establishes a list of items of two levels. The first level is called “alinea” and the second level “subalinea”. The first, “alinea”, behaves as the second level in the enumerate environment, while the second level, “subalinea”, behaves as the second level of itemize. I chose to create an “alinea” environment mimicking the enumerate environment, configuring the first and second level to behave as the standard requires. But it could perfectly have been done with itemize, so it doesn’t matter much. The option to rename is just a matter of nomenclature.

I have updated the minimal code with a few more output examples.

If my answer isn't along the right lines then, sorry, but I think I just don't understand what's wanted. Perhaps somebody else will be more familiar with what you're trying to do.

On the contrary, your answer was satisfactory. Perhaps just a few minor adjustments, but it serves the purpose. What was happening was that I was still trying to use \autoref instead of \cref. As I basically imported the package code to do the test, I hadn’t realized that you had used \cref.

There's also zref-cleveref which is, I believe, cleverer than clever. But I haven't used it. I'm still trying to understand cleveref. I'm glad you told me, because I probably would have deleted it otherwise.

I found the solution given by \def@alineaiiformatter#1#2@nil{% #2 subitem of item #1} interesting. However, it makes the text very rigid and may not be convenient, as text in general needs flexibility. Thus, I believe that a more individualized output is better, that is, “(…) first subitem (…)” instead of “(…) first subitem of item a”, for example. Another point that was not clear is: how plurals are called. I will study these clever packages to learn about them.

Indeed, I misread your target output. But I figured it was easy to do the simpler version, if that was wanted, whereas it might be less obvious how to make the simpler version more sophisticated. With a less rigid syntax, you should be able to define plurals and ranges, if desired.

@cfr , Could you enhance (increment) the solution for the simpler case, that is, to print "(…) first subitem (…)’ only instead of ‘(…) first subitem of item a (…)’, please.

Working on it. See my other comment. The base case is straightforward, but the compression isn't!

One aspect that always bothers when using a new package or class, or even when creating new packages or classes, is that often each of these new elements creates new commands, like \cref and \zref (just to name a few examples). Why is this problematic? If, for any reason, the author needs to make his document compatible with another class or use another package, he will have to search and modify the commands line by line. This is especially common if, for example, an author is invited to transform his thesis into a book by a publisher.

The ideal would be to be able to use universal commands, like \ref, for example. This would make the documents more portable. However, we have \ref, \eqref, \autoref, \zcref, \cref and possibly many other .…refs. This proliferation of commands tends to make the text rigid and not portable in terms of class or package changes. Imagine the work that will be required to migrate a huge book project from one class to another just because the publisher was changed.

Searching line by line is not usually necessary. Generally, a global replacement works provided your editor supports regular expressions. Otherwise, there is always sed or gawk. But it's anyway possible to just do something in the preamble in most cases, to provide the commands which are otherwise missing. Hopefully ltproperties will eventually replace the need for at least some of this, but it isn't yet linked in with the standard cross-referencing system. Though I doubt it will do everything cleveref or zref-clever does as it is too language-specific.

So this demonstrates an alinea environment which is distinct from the enumerate environment. It uses cleveref to handle the cross-reference format for alinea and leaves the formatting for enumerate default. Obviously, you can tweak or modify or redefine things as you wish.
It's crucial that the subalinea be an enumerate rather than an itemize since we need the counter for counting ordinals. I stole the ordinal function from english.ldf. I expect the language definition file for Brazillian has an equivalent but if it is missing - as it is for some languages - you can replace the English with the appropriate equivalents.
The code makes the following assumptions about Brazilian, a language about which I know nothing whatsoever except that it is LTR and uses Latin script:

the ordinal word has a fixed place, as it does in English i.e. if it is 'first subitem' it is also 'second subitem' ... 'umpteenth subitem';
either the language doesn't feature mutations or they do not affect the words for ordinals, items and subitems.

I'm confidant enough of the second to almost qualify as knowing a third thing about the language, albeit a negative one, simply because I know mutations are unusual.
I'm less sanguine about the first. My main reason for assuming this is that you'd hope somebody would mention it in the question if the target language used 'subitem first' but 'second subitem' etc. However, for all I know this could be extremely common. Aside from knowing it doesn't happen in at least one language and it does in at least one, I have no idea. So, hopefully you ask good questions ;).
Although this uses cleveref, it is not completely setup. If you want to use multiple referencing, compression and capitalisation, for example, you will need to add code to do that.
I put the calls to hyperref and cleveref into a hook because these should really be loaded after other packages. So, assuming somebody might want to load packages in the document preamble, it makes sense to push these back.
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.sty}
% Package name: abnt-secoes-sumario-nbr60242012-60272012
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
% Provides the abnt-secoes-sumario package with the version date
\ProvidesPackage{\jobname}[2024/05/10 Implementation of ABNT NBR 6024:2012 and NBR 6027:2012 standards version 0.1]

% Items and subitems

% The enumitem package allows you to customize lists in LaTeX, controlling the appearance and formatting: used to define items and subitems.

\RequirePackage{enumitem} 

\newlength{\lenspace} % new length to measure the length of \space
\settowidth{\lenspace}{\space} % measures the length of \space and assigns it to \lenspace

% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/718404/ addaswyd o gwestiwn lucenalex: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/718370/
\newlist{alinea}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[alinea,1]{% Settings for the first level (items)
  label=\alph*), % Defines the item label
  ref=\alph*,
  align=left,    % Defines that the items will be aligned to the left
  leftmargin=*,  % 
  labelindent=\parindent, %
  labelsep=\lenspace, % controls the space between the label and the start of the text.
} % 
\setlist[alinea,2]{% Settings for the second level (subitems)
  label=--,     % Defines the item label
  ref=\thealineai\arabictoordinal*,
  align=left,   % Defines that the items will be aligned to the left
  leftmargin=*, %
  labelindent=0pt, % 
  labelsep=\lenspace, % controls the space between the label and the start of the text. 
  parsep=0pt,   % controls the space after
  topsep=0pt    % controls the space before
} % 

% mod from english.ldf
\newcommand\@arabictoordinal{}
\newcommand\arabictoordinal{}
\def\@arabictoordinal#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or
  first\or second\or third\or fourth\or fifth\or
  sixth\or seventh\or eighth\or ninth\or tenth\else
  umpteenth\fi
}
% mod from enumitem docs
\def\arabictoordinal#1{\expandafter\@arabictoordinal\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\arabictoordinal}{\@arabictoordinal}{umpteenth}
\newcommand\alineaiiformatter{}
\newcommand\@alineaiiformatter{}
\def\@alineaiiformatter#1#2\@nil{%
  #2 subitem of item #1}
\def\alineaiiformatter#1{%
  \expandafter\@alineaiiformatter#1\@nil
}

% Creates a new list environment that behaves like the above-defined enumerate environment

\AddToHook {begindocument/before}[.]
{%
  \RequirePackage[%
  colorlinks=true,%
  linkcolor=blue,%
  citecolor=blue,%
  ]{hyperref}%
  \RequirePackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}%
  \crefname{alineai}{item}{items}%
  \crefname{alineaii}{subitem}{subitems}%
  \crefformat{alineaii}{#2\alineaiiformatter#1#3}%
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

% Insert the microtype package
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{helvet}  % Uses the 'tgheros' font, which is similar to Arial
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}  % Sets the default font as sans-serif
\usepackage{\jobname} % name of my package

\begin{document}
\OnehalfSpacing
Some text that being very long should form a paragraph, since it explains something and then enumerates some options listed in the form of items and subitems below. Here presenting two ways to do this. First with the enumerate environment:
\begin{enumerate} % calling this just for testing
  \item It is interesting to note that after line comes a subline: \label{enumi:a}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item subitem 1; \label{enumii:a:first}
    \item subitem 2;\label{enumii:a:second}
    \item subitem 3. \label{enumii:a:third}
  \end{enumerate}
  \item item 2: \label{enumi:b}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item subitem 4 \label{enumii:b:first}
    \item subitem 5 \label{enumii:b:second}
    \item subitem 6 \label{enumii:b:third}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

As mentioned in \autoref{enumi:a} and in \autoref{enumii:a:second}...

And now with the new alinea environment:
\begin{alinea}
  \item It is interesting to note that after line comes a subline. We need to understand also how this behavior will be in the alinea. \label{alinea:a}
  \begin{alinea}
    \item subalinea 1: it is not enough just to test a short word, it is necessary to see how an item behaves when the text is long. Here we had an expected behavior. \label{subalinea:a:first}
    \item subalinea 2 \label{subalinea:a:second}
    \item subalinea 3 \label{subalinea:a:third}
  \end{alinea}
  \item alinea 2 \label{alinea:b}
  \begin{alinea}
    \item subalinea 4 \label{subalinea:b:first}
    \item subalinea 5 \label{subalinea:b:second}
    \item subalinea 6 \label{subalinea:b:third}
  \end{alinea}
  \item in this item I want to understand how the distance between one item and another behaves when there is no subitem.
  \item this is important for us to understand if the items are behaving as the standard asks.
\end{alinea}

As mentioned in \cref{alinea:a} and in \cref{subalinea:a:second} ...

Just to get an idea it is good to understand how the distance between the alinea environment and the text after the alinea environment is closed.
\end{document}

I don't know if this image is any better for fiddling, but the crop doesn't seem to have worked ...


Another question: how would the code look if I had used the etoolbox package to create the commands? Would it be interesting to make them robust?

@lucenalex I try to avoid etoolbox these days, although it is still handy for patching. LaTeX itself offers better options and a clearer syntax. You could protect some of the commands, yes, but some you don't want to protect, right?

@lucenalex I'll try to post something later. It's complicated because you don't really want to group them if they belong to different items, but that means you need to save that information. But then you need a splitting trick again, which seems like it should be unnecessary .... I guess you could save properties, but then nothing works out-of-the-box, which is a pain.

I’m curious to know how this code would work for plurals. For example: ‘In the first and second sub-items of item a (…)’ or ‘In items a, b, and c, (…)’.

The same examples, but this time in the Portuguese version.
"Na primeira e segunda subalíneas da alínea a (...)"; "Nas alíneas a, b e c (...)".

@cfr You may be interested in a little zref-clever trick in the other answer. ;-)

@lucenalex I have the simpler formatting working for plurals and ranges, but I can't figure out how to deal with cases where somebody cites \cref{sublinea:a:first,sublinea:b:second,sublinea:a:third}, where you don't want them compressed ....

Since @cfr suggested zref-clever here is one way to do it using zref facilities (a new property ordref, which we use to store the ordinal of the reference, and then refer to that later):
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazilian,english]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{alinea}{enumerate}{2}

\newlength{\lenspace} % new length to measure the length of \space
\settowidth{\lenspace}{\space} % measures the length of \space and assigns it to \lenspace
\setlist[alinea,1]{% Settings for the first level (items)
  label=\alph*), % Defines the item label
  ref=\alph*,
  align=left,    % Defines that the items will be aligned to the left
  leftmargin=*,  %
  labelindent=\parindent, %
  labelsep=\lenspace, % controls the space between the label and the start of the text.
}
\setlist[alinea,2]{% Settings for the second level (subitems)
  label=--,     % Defines the item label
  ref=\arabic*,
  align=left,   % Defines that the items will be aligned to the left
  leftmargin=*, %
  labelindent=0pt, %
  labelsep=\lenspace, % controls the space between the label and the start of the text.
  parsep=0pt,   % controls the space after
  topsep=0pt    % controls the space before
}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{
  countertype = { alineai=alinea, alineaii=subalinea } ,
}
\zcRefTypeSetup{alinea}{
  Name-sg = Alínea ,
  name-sg = alínea ,
  Name-pl = Alíneas ,
  name-pl = alíneas ,
}
% The use of refbounds with a hard-coded singular name won't work for multiple
% labels, plural etc., so you can only use a single label when referring to a
% subalinea. But see below.
\zcRefTypeSetup{subalinea}{
  Name-sg = ,
  name-sg = ,
  Name-pl = ,
  name-pl = ,
  refbounds = {,,,~subalínea}
}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{ordref}{\ordinalstring{\@currentcounter}[f]}
\zref@addprop{main}{ordref}
\makeatother

\usepackage[%
  colorlinks=true,%
  linkcolor=blue,%
  citecolor=blue,%
]{hyperref}%

\begin{document}
Some text that being very long should form a paragraph, since it explains
something and then enumerates some options listed in the form of items and
subitems below. Here presenting two ways to do this.

And now with the new alinea environment:
\begin{alinea}
\item It is interesting to note that after line comes a subline. We need to
  understand also how this behavior will be in the alinea. \label{alinea:a}
  \begin{alinea}
  \item subalinea 1: it is not enough just to test a short word, it is
    necessary to see how an item behaves when the text is long. Here we had an
    expected behavior. \label{subalinea:a:first}
  \item subalinea 2 \label{subalinea:a:second}
  \item subalinea 3 \label{subalinea:a:third}
  \end{alinea}
\item alinea 2 \label{alinea:b}
  \begin{alinea}
  \item subalinea 4 \label{subalinea:b:first}
  \item subalinea 5 \label{subalinea:b:second}
  \item subalinea 6 \label{subalinea:b:third}
  \end{alinea}
\item in this item I want to understand how the distance between one item and
  another behaves when there is no subitem.
\item this is important for us to understand if the items are behaving as the
  standard asks.
\end{alinea}

As mentioned in the \zcref[ref=ordref]{subalinea:a:second} of \zcref{alinea:a}
...

% And in Portuguese too, with correct gender etc.
\begin{otherlanguage*}{brazilian}
Como mencionado na \zcref[ref=ordref]{subalinea:a:second} da \zcref{alinea:a}
...

% But we can get plural with a little manual work.
Na \zcref[ref=ordref,refbounds=]{subalinea:b:first,subalinea:a:second}
subalíneas da \zcref{alinea:a} ...
\end{otherlanguage*}

Just to get an idea it is good to understand how the distance between the
alinea environment and the text after the alinea environment is closed.

\end{document}



Very nice indeed! What I can't get working is the mixed case with simple formatting where you have e.g the first, second and third subitems of a and the fourth and fifth or b, and you're not typesetting the 'of a'/'of b'.

@cfr :-) About mixing, hmm... Multiple labels for this kind of structure is already stretching. Fully generalizing this will probably require some sort of preprocessing, I'm not sure it is worth it. What zref(-clever) could do here is somehow store the "parent" of a subalinea, so that one did not lose the relation between them. This might ease this kind of work and, of course, it'd make the referencing easier too and less error prone.

Do you know whether it is common for languages to have the additional complication that some ordinals go first and some second?

@cfr What is "common" I don't know, but things can get pretty complicated... For example, for Japanese, the name should go after the reference (as in this question), and it is just lucky it is invariant to number (https://github.com/gusbrs/zref-clever/issues/6).

In Welsh: the subitem first, the second subitem, ..., the tenth subitem, the oneth subitem on ten .... And you also have mutations in the mix. If subitem is just a placeholder, the mutations will depend on the word substituted. Moreover, they may also depend on context, if we're not using the definite article. And I suspect Welsh is simple compared to languages which differ more significantly from English.

@cfr Ouch! the order depends on the value!... That's a tough one! :-) Regarding context, article etc. there's some (limited) support for those in zref-clever: declension support, and some gender, number checks (I called them "nudges"). Certainly still short for Welsh, I guess.
